# When one class implements another interface, will its children also, implicitly, implement that interface?

Tags: java, comparable, subclassing

I have an generic abstract class, `BString`, which expects one of its types to implement `Comparable`. Another class, `NGram` extends `BString`, passing `String` as the comparable type. A final class, `BinarySearchTree` expects keys which extend `Comparable`.

Why am I unable to create a `BinarySearchTree` with `NGram` as the key type? Does the implements `Comparable` declaration for `BString` strictly hold for `BString` and none of its descendants? I have included the class declarations below, and note that while `BString` overrides `compareTo`, `NGram` does not. Below is the requested code.

```
public abstract class BString<Alphabet extends Comparable<Alphabet>> implements Iterable<Alphabet>, Comparable<BString<Alphabet>> {
protected FixedSizeFIFOWorkList<Alphabet> str;

}
public BString(Alphabet[] str) {
    this.str = new CircularArrayFIFOQueue<Alphabet>(str.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        this.str.add(str[i]);
    }
}

public class NGram extends BString<String> {
    public NGram(String[] str) {
        super(str);
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
    extends ComparableDictionary<K, V> {
    // The root of the BST. Root is null if and only if the tree is empty.
    protected BSTNode root;

    /**
     * Create an empty binary search tree.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        super();
        this.root = null;
    }
}

new BinarySearchTree<NGram,Dictionary<AlphabeticString, Integer>>()
```

When I go to actually create the `BinarySearchTree`, as in the last line of the code, I am given the following message:

> Bound mismatch: The type `NGram` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<K extends 
>    Comparable<K>>` of the type `BinarySearchTree<K,V>`

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: a class can't extend an interface. it can only implement one. and yes, if class A implements interface B, and class C extends A, then class C implements B

Comment: Why would the BinarySearchTree complain?

Comment: can you fix your code and post the code for `BinarySearchTree` too?

Comment: code has been updated, any more seemed unnecessary , but can include more if desired.