# BinaryTree expects Comparable, subclass of another which implements Comparable not working

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have an generic abstract class, `BString`, which expects one of its types to implement `Comparable`. Another class, `NGram` extends `BString`, passing `String` as the comparable type. A final class, `BinarySearchTree` expects keys which extend `Comparable`.

Why am I unable to create a `BinarySearchTree` with `NGram` as the key type?  I have included the class declarations below, and note that while `BString` overrides `compareTo`, `NGram` does not.

When I go to actually create the `BinarySearchTree`, as in the last line of the code, I am given the following message:

> Bound mismatch: The type `NGram` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<K extends Comparable<K>>` of the type `BinarySearchTree<K,V>`

Below is the code.

```
public abstract class BString<Alphabet extends Comparable<Alphabet>> implements Iterable<Alphabet>, Comparable<BString<Alphabet>> {
protected FixedSizeFIFOWorkList<Alphabet> str;

}
public BString(Alphabet[] str) {
    this.str = new CircularArrayFIFOQueue<Alphabet>(str.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        this.str.add(str[i]);
    }
}

public class NGram extends BString<String> {
    public NGram(String[] str) {
        super(str);
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
    extends ComparableDictionary<K, V> {
    // The root of the BST. Root is null if and only if the tree is empty.
    protected BSTNode root;

    /**
     * Create an empty binary search tree.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        super();
        this.root = null;
    }
}

new BinarySearchTree<NGram,Dictionary<AlphabeticString, Integer>>()
```

Comment: Since `NGram` doesn't implement `Comparable<NGram>`, why are you surprised that it cannot be used as `K` in the `BinarySearchTree`, where it is bound as `K extends Comparable<K>`?

Comment: @Andreas due to this previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284824/when-one-class-implements-another-interface-will-its-children-also-implicitly. Do the comments (no answer yet) not suggest that it would be allowed?

Comment: No. The [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284824/when-one-class-implements-another-interface-will-its-children-also-implicitly#comment101064860_57284824) suggests that `NGram implements Comparable<BString<String>>`, not that `NGram implements Comparable<NGram>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have declared:

```
BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

When you are using `NGram` as K, it is expected to implement `Comparable<NGram>`. Since it does not implement `Comparable<NGram>` you get the error.

**Edit**

More details on this issue and workaround:

When a superclass implements `Comparable<SuperClass>`, the subclass can't again implement `Comparable<SubClass>`. This will mean subclass is implementing the same Generic type twice. Java does not allow it.

The workaround is to implement `Comparable<SuperClass>` in the subclass too. In the method implementation, check for subclass type and handle it. Prefer not to implement `Comparable at all you have a class hierarchy. Instead, use Comparator.

So, to fix your issue in the current situation declare `BinarySearchTree` the following way in order to allow `NGram` as `K`:

```
BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

Otherwise, get rid of `Comparable` and use `Comparator` instead. Notice that, without the above changes you can use `BString` as `K` while constructing `BinarySearchTree` since it implements `Comparable<BString>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `NGram` implements `Comparable<BString<Alphabet>>` (inherited from `BString`).  For it to satisfy the bounds requirement for `BinarySearchTree`'s type parameter `K`, it would need to implement `Comparable<NGram>`, instead.  The latter is not a subtype of the former.

The essential problem is that `BinarySearchTree`'s requirement is too restrictive.  In order to compare two `NGram`s, it doesn't *need* that class to be comparable specifically to itself.  It would be sufficient for it to be comparable to any of its own superclasses.  Precisely that concept can be expressed like so:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
        extends ComparableDictionary<K, V> // ...
```

Of course, that might require a loosening in `ComparableDictionary`, too.